# Pulling transaction data based on one monthly data that's stored daily

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table called transactions and I'm looking for one specific transaction type for every person.

Here are my tables:

**Account**

```
   DateTime     | Balance   | PersonID
   -------------+-----------+----------
    2018-01-02  |   0.00.   | 1
    2018-01-04  |   3.00    | 1
    2018-02-02  |   0.00    |  1
```

**Transactions**

```
      DateTime   | TypeCode | PersonID
      -----------+----------+----------
      2018-01-05 |     5    |  1
      2018-02-04 |     5    |  1
```

Basically I need to pull only the transactions that never had a balance > 0 during the same month as the transaction.

So in the above example data, I would only pull the 2nd transaction.

I haven't gotten far with the query

```
Select * 
From transaction t
Join account a On t.personid = a.personid
Where a.balance > 0
```

I'm trying to think of how I could maybe use a CTE or temp table to pull this but I'm not sure on how to group the data. The account table has one record per day for each person.

Comment: A `Max( Balance )` and `group by PersonId, Year( AccountDateTime ), Month( AccountDateTime )` might move you along the path. Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: Sorry, I was strapped for time and posted from mobile. Thank you for the answer, I don't know how I didn't realize to use max!